# Many audio devices with same name: how to use them in asound.conf?

Tags: audio, alsa

I'd like to create a new PCM device in ALSA, thanks to these [ALSA PCM plugins](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html) in `/etc/asound.conf`:

```
pcm.blah {
  type rate
  slave {
    pcm <device1>
    rate 48000
  }
}
```

But what name to use in `<device1>`?

Doing `aplay -L` shows many devices having same name (see below).

**How to select *precisely* one device in `asound.conf`, when it seems that many devices have the same name?** (e.g. there are at least 3 devices named `default` in the list below)

```
root@samplerbox:~# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
blah
default:CARD=ALSA
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=ALSA
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=DAC
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=DAC
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=LPD8
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=LPD8
    Default Audio Device
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have three devices named `default`.
The three device names are `default:CARD=ALSA`, `default:CARD=DAC`, and `default:CARD=LPD8`.

But if you don't want another resampling plugin, you probably should use one of the `hw` or `dmix` devices.

Comment: So it should be `slave {    pcm default:CARD=ALSA ...` ?   Second thing, I don't understand what you said about "another resampling plugin", why hw or dmix? (I don't know anything about them)

Comment: In some places over the internet, I find things like `pcm "hw:0,0"` or `hw:1,1` or `card 2`. What are these? Another way to access to a precise device? Are they correct?

Comment: Strings containing some special charactes must be "quoted". There are several ways of giving parameters to device names; `hw:0` and `hw:ALSA` and `hw:CARD=0` and `hw:CARD=ALSA` are all the same.

Comment: Ok thanks! Now I get another error when I try to create a PCM rate convert with the code pasted in my question : `Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934`... Any idea?

Comment: Apparently, PulseAudio is using some parameters not supports by this combination of devices. Does it work with aplay? And what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No it's not PulseAudio (I'm working on a minimal distro, no PulseAudio installed). This happens when I want to list all devices with PyAudio, [as described here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/994#issuecomment-142096099). 
I'm trying this `pcm.convert` [as suggested here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/994#issuecomment-141051047).

The problem I'm trying to solve:  Audio playback with PyAudio doesn't work correctly on RaspberryPi. In this Github issue, @yienyien suggests to create a `rate` change.